# laravel - reach the json on the controller using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

This is my ajax:

```js
$.ajax({ 
    url: '{{ route('add.orders') }}',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({ sepet }),
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```

This is my controller page:

```
public function addOrders(Request $request) {
    $test = $request->sepet;
    
    return $test;
}
```

And I'm seeing the data, there is no problem. Log is like below:

[image]

But the problem is that, in the controller I want to reach the first element of `id` of array.

```
public function addOrders(Request $request) {
    $test = $request->sepet[0];

    return $test;
}
```

This is working there is no problem. I am getting this log:

[image]

But if I use:

```
public function addOrders(Request $request) {
    $test = $request->sepet[0]->id;

    return $test;
}
```

This is not working. How can I reach the `id` on the controller?

I have to insert to database with coming json like `food_price`, `id`, `foot_title`.

How to reach these?

Comment: And what is the error ? What is your actual problem ?

Comment: Do you want only `id` in your controller?

Comment: Actual problem is that i can not getting food_price on the controller page. I have to insert it to the database, but can not do it

Comment: No, i dont want only id.  I want all elements of first array. Ex: $id = $request->sepet[0]->id;   $price = $request->sepet[0]->food_price

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? What does "getting this log" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data is coming from a request, they will be in an associative array and not an object.

```
public function addOrders(Request $request) {
    $test = $request->sepet[0]['id'];

    return $test;
}
```

if you wan to loop the whole

```
public function addOrders(Request $request) {
    foreach($request->sepet as $sepet) {
        $id = $sepet['id'];
        $foodTitle = $sepet['food_title'];
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use like below code

```
$testData = json_decode($request->sepet,true);

foreach($testData as $data){

    $id = $data->id;

    $food_price = $data->food_price;

}
```

Comment: ....are you sure? `JSON.decode` would throw a pretty hard error message in common PHP

Comment: @NicoHaase, sorry it's my mistake of syntax.